# Adding property in random points using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest

I am trying to do Random Forest in Google Earth Engine. I generate *landslide class* and *non-landslide class* in a region

```
var landslide = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(Iburi, 500)
var nonlandslide = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(outlandslide, 500)
```

Then, merge it using

```
var samples = landslide.merge(nonlandslide)
```

However, it comes to error when I run the Random Forest

According to the [Supervised Classification](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/classification)
 page in the Google Developers Guide, I have to provide

> a property that stores the known class label and properties storing numeric values for the predictors

How do I create a property with numeric values in the samples generated from Random points?

Answer (score 1):

You map over each collection (before the merge), assigning a class to each feature:

```
var landslide = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(Iburi, 500)
    .map(function(f) {
        return f.set('class', 1)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's help me a lot